# Cannot access struct field when using Borrow constraint

Tags: rust

Why I cannot access path field? Can I do something with that?

```rust
use std::borrow::Borrow;

struct Node{
    path: String,
}

fn foo<T: Borrow<Node>>(a: T) {
    let x = a.path;
}

fn main(){
    let node = Node {path:"test".to_string()};
    foo(&node);
    foo(&mut node);
}
```

```
error[E0609]: no field `path` on type `T`
 --> src/main.rs:8:15
  |
7 | fn foo<T: Borrow<Node>>(a: T) {
  |        - type parameter 'T' declared here
8 |     let x = a.path;
  |               ^^^^
```

[code on rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=818297f747ba9af79824bd91eea2d0ee)

Comment: In addition to @kmdreko's answer, it's also worth nothing that you may find [`AsRef`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html) (`a.as_ref()`) slightly easier to use, at it is the same basic idea as `Borrow<T>`, but without any restrictions on `T`. (For `Borrow<T>`, instances of `T` must be invariant under `Hash`, `Eq`, and `Ord`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html) trait does not provide any syntactical sugar, it simply defines a `borrow()` method that returns the `&T`. So getting the `path` field would be:

```
a.borrow().path
```

---

With that said, you may also be interested in the [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) trait, which *does* have syntactical sugar to access the field directly:

```
fn foo<T: Deref<Target = Node>>(a: T) {
    let x = a.path.clone();
}
```

See it working on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=56ffd562f8bd1c50cf6598be18fb1ca4).

Comment: [cleaner working example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c072c31f68e06f4436fed268fd8b10a3) with `Rc` and `RefCell`